# Angular Http - How to cancel outdated request

Tags: angular, angular-http

So basically I have a function that makes 2 HTTP requests to the server every time I receive a new data from signalR which will be fired so many times. So `getitemCount` function will be called so many times. Therefore It will hit the server so many times as well.

`getitemCount` is a promised because I used `toPromise()` operator to convert it from Observable.

What I am trying to do is: when receiving an update from the server, If there are any `getitemCount` is going on. It will be canceled and make a new request instead.

```
export class LeftNavigationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    typeACount: number = 0;
    typeBCount: number = 0;    

    constructor(
        private itemService: service.ItemService,        
        private signalR: service.SignalRService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriptions = [            
            this.signalR.itemCreated.subscribe(item => this.onUpdatingData()),
            this.signalR.itemUpdated.subscribe(item => this.onUpdatingData()),
            this.signalR.itemDeleted.subscribe(itemId => this.onUpdatingData())]
    }

    onUpdatingData() {
        Promise.all([
            this.itemService.getitemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_A),
            this.itemService.getitemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_B)])
            .then(response => this.gettingCountDone(response))
    }

    gettingCountDone(response) {
        this.typeACount = <any>response[0];
        this.typeBCount = <any>response[1];        
    }
}
```

I have used [switchMap](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/search_with_switchmap.html) for implementing the search before, but still not be able to archive it on the current use case.

Anybody can give me a suggestion. What I have done so far is using Observable instead of Promise and using folkJoin to combine the result. But it will behave the same as what I am having at the moment.

```
onUpdatingData() {
    Rx.Observable.forkJoin(this.itemService.getitemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_A), this.itemService.getitemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_B), (r1, r2) => {

    })
}
```

Comment: i think unsubscribe should do that

Comment: Will it looks like I assign the Observable to a subscription variable and then every time I go to onUpdatingData, I check If the variable not null and unsubscribe?

Comment: Exactly you will need to keep all subscription. But again I am not sure since I've never done that just logically it should work

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about that before. But it would be great If Observable has supported it with an operator. By the way, I will try the unsubsribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just try localy and yes unsubscribe do its job

```
const subscription = this.http.get(`/api/v2/url`).subscribe();
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

And i see that request is cancelled in chrome